# Index (zero based) must be greater than or... Working with the Bit.ly API

Tags: api, c#-4.0, bit.ly

I'm working (actually more like playing) around with the Bit.ly API, and keep getting the error in the title of this question. So I'm going to show you the code and hopefuly someone can help me resolve this. First the client side code.

```
var x = service.GetClicks(url, service.BitlyLogin, service.BitlyAPIKey);
Console.WriteLine(x);

Console.ReadLine();
```

And this is the code that's being called

```
public List<int> GetClicks(string url, string login, string key)
{
    List<int> clicks = new List<int>();
    url = Uri.EscapeUriString(url);
    string reqUri =
        String.Format("http://api.bit.ly/v3/clicks?" +
        "login={0}&apiKey={1}&shortUrl={2}&format=xml" +
        login, key, url);

    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(reqUri);
    req.Timeout = 10000; // 10 seconds

    Stream stm = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();


    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(stm);

    // error checking for xml
    if (doc["response"]["status_code"].InnerText != "200")
        throw new WebException(doc["response"]["status_txt"].InnerText);

    XmlElement el = doc["response"]["data"]["clicks"];
    clicks.Add(int.Parse(el["global_clicks"].InnerText));
    clicks.Add(int.Parse(el["user_clicks"].InnerText));

    return clicks;
}
```

As you can see it's very simple code, nothing complicated, and I can see nothing that causes this error. Anyone out there who has worked with(the full error is Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.) the Bit.ly API and can lend a hand?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I narrowed it down to a place where I was using string.Format to build an array and has less in the string.Format than what was supposed to. I had it go to Index 3 but only filled to Index 2

Comment: I managed to throw this another way. If the above doesn't work for you, check that you haven't written something like `foo.AppendFormat("{1}", baa);` instead of `foo.AppendFormat("{0}", baa);` - note the index.

Answer (score 4):

Instead this

```
string reqUri =
        String.Format("http://api.bit.ly/v3/clicks?" +
        "login={0}&apiKey={1}&shortUrl={2}&format=xml" + login, key, url);
```

Use this

```
string reqUri = String.Format("http://api.bit.ly/v3/clicks?login={0}&apiKey={1}&shortUrl={2}&format=xml", login, key, url);
```

Notice that I just changed the plus sign with the comma before "*login, key, url);*" at the end of the **String.Format()**.

Answer (score 1):

Not for your specific case, but I ran into this: make sure that, if you have multiple parameters, you send them as an array of objects instead of an IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<object> myArgs = ...;
string toFormat = "{0} xyz {1}";

String.Format(toFormat, myArgs);
// ERROR, since myArgs is one argument whereas the string template requires two

String.Format(toFormat, myArgs.ToArray());
// Valid, as the Format() accepts an array of objects to fill all arguments in the string
```